# What is the significance of the fact that every month that has a Biblical holiday in it is a 30-day month?

Tags: calendar, yom-tov

Rosh HaShanah, Yom Kippur, and Sukkos are all in Tishrei, which has 30 days.

Pesach is in Nissan, which has 30 days.

Shavuos is in Sivan, which has 30 days.

What is the significance of this fact, that every month that has a Biblical holiday in it is a 30-day month? (Although month lengths weren't predetermined in the times of Tanach, I thought it was an interesting observation that later when the set calendar was made, it was arranged to be this way.)

Comment: Probably because they always come after months with 29 days. if they varied then Yom Tov sheni would become Yom tov rishon. That's sufficient for me. The relevant Talmudic passage for these rules is RH 19b

Comment: @DoubleAA Is your point that Nissan varies? That’s not my point. It seems too big of a coincidence that all three months containing Yamim Tovim are thirty days - if Sivan had 29, for instance, I wouldn’t have asked.

Comment: @doniel I don't understand where I said Nissan varies. If 1 of Adar [II] or Elul would have 30 the safek day of Yom Tov would come before the Vadai day, unlike the other set of holidays, which would be weird/confusing. Sivan is two months after Nissan so it's very likely the same length. So it's no surprise that all three months are the same length. It's expected!

Comment: @DoubleAA This is a very good answer! Why don't you put it in the answer section? Are answers which are definately correct, but not sourced by anyone else, not valid by MY rules? How about if you wrote it on "yoursite", and then answered here " Rabbi DoubleAA says HERE (linked) that..." ? Would it suddenly become valid?

Comment: @ribbis no it doesn't explain why they all aren't 29. That probably has to do with the tradition that Elul always should be 29. It also doesn't explain why the months themselves aren't the variable months. Anyway we should have expected the months to be the same since they are all odd number months anyway

Comment: Interesting question. But there are two slight "problems" - 1) As you stated, the Biblical holidays were not based on any notion of a specific month length. So, my own thinking is that it is coincidental (OK, Hashem planned that Hillel II should make the calendar alternate the way that he did.) and 2) Shabbat is also a Biblical holiday. It doesn't always occur in a 30-day month.

Comment: @DanF First one is why I rephrased the question the way I did. Second one I think is semantics.

Comment: Nothing, 1. in times of Kiddush Hachodesh, it was totally arbitrary and in the hands of the Beis Din. 2. when the fixed calendar was introduced, the main idea was to count full and lack months alternatively - full/lack/full/lack, starting with Elul. Those 3 festivals fall on 1, 7, 9 months and are automatically full.

Comment: @AlBerko Point 1 I noted in the question. Point 2 - I tried intimating this earlier in the comments, but I’m looking for a deeper understanding, not just why it works out that way.

Comment: Not really an answer (and similar to Double AA), but if Elul had 30 days, first day Rosh Hashanah would fall out on 30th of Elul (and hence on last day of previous year) -- would make things confusing.